# Xquery: returning multiple data elements using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following `xml`:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <name>Sample name</name>
        <attribute id="sampleid" location="sampleLocation" type="sampleType"/>
        <price>12345</price> 
    </product>
</Products>
```

How can I return the following data from this XML for a given name (always unique):

```
1. location (e.g. "sampleLocation")
2. type (e.g. "sampleType")
3. price (e.g. 12345
```

I currently am able to query each *individually* to return values, but im not sure of the syntax to return multiple values together.

**Example of individual query for location:**

```
 ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query(
                        format("//Products/Product[name='%s']" +
                                        "/attribute/@Location/string()"
                                , StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(journey_Name)
                        ));
```

The query above will return: "sampleLocation".

Comment: What XQuery processor and what API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns a sequence of three strings:

```
/Products/Product/(string(attribute/@location), string(attribute/@type), string(price))
```

How to return a sequence of three strings to your Java app depends on the XQuery processor and API that you are using, which you haven't told us.